# UITableView Data Source

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tablecell

I am receiving 2 errors.

The first I am confused about because everything is inside the  {} so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

> "Type 'StoriesViewController' does not conform to protocol
>   'UITableViewDataSource' Clicking fix adds:
>
> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
>   IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
>           <#code#>
>       }

**and 2nd error**

> Ambiguous use of 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

I assigned the table cell the identifier "storyCell" from the main storyboard

Full code:

```
// creating a custom color
extension UIColor {
    static var darkmodeGray = UIColor.init(red: 41/255, green: 42/255, blue: 47/255, alpha: 1)
}


class StoriesViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        <#code#>
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let storySelection = [("WeekOne"),("WeekTwo"),("WeekThree"),("WeekFour"),("WeekFive"),("WeekSix")]
    let storySelectionImages = [UIImage(named: "WeekOne"), UIImage(named: "WeekTwo"), UIImage(named: "WeekThree"), UIImage(named: "WeekFour"), UIImage(named: "WeekFive"), UIImage(named: "WeekSix")]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor .darkmodeGray
    }

    //Part One
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //Part Two
    func  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return storySelection.count
    }

    //Part Three
    private func tableView(tableView :UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("storyCell", forIndexPath: IndexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.CoverArt.image=self.storySelectionImages[indexPath .row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I’d suggest rewriting your methods and making use of Xcode’s code completion to make sure you enter them correctly.

Comment: Your suggestion helped fix the 2nd error I was receiving. I am still confused about the first part when using code completion.

What code does it want there?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        <#code#>
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is Swift 2(!) code.

The usual way to update the signature of a method is to comment it out, retype it and use code completion.

Or read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource), that's always a good idea.

The three methods are (`numberOfSections` can be omitted if there is only one section)

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return storySelection.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "storyCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.CoverArt.image = self.storySelectionImages[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I rewrote the methods. 
    
    //Part Two
    func  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return storySelection.count
    }
    
    
    //Part Three
    
    func tableview(tableView :UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "storyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TableViewCell
        return cell
    }

I'm still receiving the first error.

Comment: Remove the `cellForRowAt` method st the beginning of the class and use **exactly** my suggested code for part three. Your signature is still wrong.